# Special list view

Tags: python, list

Having a list like:

```
 >>> l = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0]
```

How could I implement a Proxy that computes the sum of the repeated numbers, and the indexing operation behaves like:

```
>>> proxy = Proxy(l) 
>>> proxy[0]
0
>>> proxy[1] 
3 
>>> proxy[2]  
0     
>>> proxy[3] 
6 
>>> proxy[4]  
0
```

The underlying list must be invariant. The Proxy would be a class that receives the list and implements **getitem**, like:

```
class Proxy:
    
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l 

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        pass
```

I need some kind of "on the fly" computation in the **getitem** method. I need to keep the list absolutely invariant, in order to leverage some framework.

Comment: What would a proxy be?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `sum`:

```
from itertools import groupby

proxy = lambda lst: [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(lst)]

p = proxy([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0])
p
# [0, 3, 0, 6, 0]
```

Or as a class:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = l
        self._data = [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(iterable)]
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._data[index]
```

Some docs:

- [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)
- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your question. But I've implemented a simple function to do as you wanted. (Or at least what I think you've wanted)

```
def Proxy(lst):
    result = [0]
    last_value = lst[0]
    for item in lst:
        if item == last_value:
            result[len(result)-1] += item
        else:
            result.append(item)
        last_value = item
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply iterate on the list, keeping the previous value to compare.
Something like:

```
from typing import List
def proxy(lst: List[int]):
    res = {}
    prev = None  # Initial value, would be different from first item
    index = -1   # Initial value, would be incremented on first item
    for num in lst:
        if num == prev:
            res[index] += num
        else:
            index += 1
            res[index] = num
        prev = num
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter


class View:
    def __init__(self, l):
        self.l = Counter(l)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.l.get(index, 0) * index


proxy = View([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0])
print(proxy[2]) #6
```

Comment: May be keeping both structures, the list and the counter could solve my problem. I'll try.